# Flask and Connexion[Swager UI] The name '/api' is already registered for a different blueprint

Tags: python, api, flask

Estoy siguiendo este [tutorial](https://realpython.com/flask-connexion-rest-api/)

Logre una estructura como esta:

### [image: Estructura de archivos de mi API]

segun el tutorial si me dirijo a http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/ui deberia tener una GUI de mi API, pero al intentar entrar me sale este error: `ValueError: The name '/api' is already registered for a different blueprint. Use 'name=' to provide a unique name.`

Codigo de app.py:

```
from flask import render_template
import connexion

app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir="./")
app.add_api("swagger.yml")

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    try:
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
    
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        app.destroy()`
```

Codigo de Swagger.yml:

```
# swagger.yml

openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: "Flask REST API"
  description: "Una API para manejar redes"
  version: "0.1.0"

servers:
  - url: "/api"

components:
  schemas:
    Host:
      type: "object"
      required:
        - hname
      properties:
        hname:
          type: "string"
        ip:
          type: "string"

paths:
...
  /topologia:
    
    get:
      operationId: "topology_scan.scan_all"
      tags:
        - "topology"
      summary: "Regresar json con los routers existentes en la topología y ligas a sus routers vecinos"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "Se escaneo toda la topologia"
 ...
```

Y codigo de la funcion que se llama con la API:

```
def scan_topology_premade(ip):
    topology = {}
    request = scapy.ARP() 
  
    request.pdst = str(ip)
    broadcast = scapy.Ether() 
  
    broadcast.dst = 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'
  
    request_broadcast = broadcast / request 
    clients = scapy.srp(request_broadcast, timeout = 1)[0] 
    for element in clients: 
        #print(element[1].psrc + "      " + element[1].hwsrc)
        topology[socket.getfqdn(element[1].psrc)] = ({
                "IP":[element[1].psrc],
                "MAC":[element[1].hwsrc],
                "Subredes":[]
        })

    
    if bool(topology):
        j_topology = json.dumps(topology, indent=4)       
        return j_topology
```

Anteriormente funcionaba todo a la perfeccion, pero despues de un par de veces que detuve el programa y actualice el codigo me empeso a arrojar el error.

Estuve intentando resolverlo de varias formas y una que "funciono" fue agregar `app = app.app` en app.py, pero ya no me deja ingresar a swagger-ui ni a mi API. Es mi primera vez usando flask y no se muy bien que se debe hacer, busque que deberia usar flask.Blueprint pero como uso connexion no logro ver donde agrego esa opcion.